# Сессия для языкового переключателя

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток** 

Сделал языковой переключатель и вот такую логику от которой подключая языковые пакеты и отображаю на выбранном языке данные.

```
 if (isset($_GET['language_id']) && !empty($_GET['language_id']) && $_GET['language_id'] == "en") {
        __IncludeLang($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $templateFolder . '/lang/'.'en'.'/'.basename(__FILE__));
        session_start();
        if (isset($_REQUEST['language_id']))
            $_SESSION["language_id"] = ($_REQUEST['language_id'] == 'ru') ? 'ru' : 'en';
    } else if (isset($_GET['language_id']) && !empty($_GET['language_id']) && $_GET['language_id'] == "ru" || !isset($_GET['language_id']) && empty($_GET['language_id'])) {
        __IncludeLang($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $templateFolder . '/lang/'.'ru'.'/'.basename(__FILE__));
        $_SESSION['language_id'] = "ru";
    }
```

Данная логика подключена в header.php. В рамках текущей страницы все отлично работает, но если например я наглавной странице переключил язык на английский, далее захожу в категорию товаров, то там уже опять отображается руссая версия сайта и опять нужно делать выбор языка. Понятно что тут отрабатывает else if, но как можно сделать такую логику что бы от выбранного языка, сохранить его в сессию, и далее это же значение использовать на другой странице? Подскажите пожалуйста. По умолчанию у меня русский, я сейчас пытаюсь сделать что бы если выбрали язык то на основании этого отображаю данные на нужном языке, и если не выбрали язык то отображаю так же на русском.
Или какие еще есть варианты? Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом =)

Answer (score 1):

**ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ** вариантом во всех смыслах будет передавать идентификатор языка в ссылке, каждый раз. Например `site.ru/about/` - русская версия, а `site.ru/en/about/` - английская. Или `site.ru/about/?lang=kz` (такой себе вариант).

**НИКОГДА** не используйте для этого сессии, куки и прочее.

Как сможете сделать роутинг с языками, сами же выкинете свою поделку и сможете написать универсальный определитель/переключатель языка.

P.S. Языковой код для казахского языка - **kk**, а не kz))

Comment: я пробовал в начале сделать роутинг с UrlRewrite, но что то не получилось, после выбрал сессии.

Comment: @Dolphin вот лучше реврайтинг домучайте до конца))

Comment: я прописал пути, но по данному пути не чего не открывается, можете привести пример как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Скажем так... У вас есть путь site.com/en/about/ - первым делом вы должны проверить наличие языка, а потом уже получить страницу. Если язык есть, берете его версию при получении данных, если нет, значит берете по умолчанию, например, русский.

Comment: а почему нельзя использовать для этого сессии и куки?

Comment: @Dolphin потому что это а) неявно - пользователь фактически не видит на каком он языке находится, б) не SEO-friendly - поисковики просканируют только одну версию вашего сайта, в) оооочень плохая практика - просто потому что